# Find Functions That Can Be Inverted from Their Sums

Tags: functions, summation, inverse

I have the following situation:$$
 f_1(x_1) + f_1(x_2) + f_1(x_3) + \cdots + f_1(x_n) = c_1\\
 f_2(x_1) + f_2(x_2) + f_2(x_3) + \cdots + f_2(x_n) = c_2\\
 \vdots\\
 f_n(x_1) + f_n(x_2) + f_n(x_3) + \cdots + f_n(x_n) = c_n
$$These formulae are evaluated at a particular vector $\vec{x}$, producing a vector $\vec{c}$ of constants.  Now, given this vector $\vec{c}$, I want to reconstruct the original $\vec{x}$.  **What** $f_i$**s should I choose that will let me do this?**

There are two constraints: $f_i$ is bounded on $(0,1)$ and $\left[f_i(x_j)=0\right] \rightarrow \left[x_j \in \{0,1\}\right]$ (and $f_i(x_j)$ is $0$ in at least one point).

There are, however, some simplifying assumptions.  Each $x_i \in [0,1]$ and $\left[x_i=x_j\right] \rightarrow \left[\left[i=j\right] \vee \left[f_k(x_i)=f_k(x_j)=0\right]\right]$.  Furthermore, **the order of the components of** $\vec{x}$ **is irrelevant** (that is, *reconstructing any permutation* of $\vec{x}$ is fine).

A closed-form solution is ideal, but a numerical solution scaling gracefully with $n$ is acceptable too.  Partial solutions for $n \geq 4$ will be accepted if there is no general approach.

---

I have tried a number of things, but my best attempt so far is the rather basic:$$
 f_i(x_j) := x_j^{i}
$$So that we have:$$
 f_1(x_j) := x_j^1\\
 f_2(x_j) := x_j^2\\
 \vdots\\
 f_n(x_j) := x_j^n
$$Viewed this way, each equation represents an $n$-dimensional [superquadric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superquadrics).  For $n=2$, a closed form exists (intersection of line with circle quadrant).  For $n=3$, I used [multidimensional Newton iteration](http://www.math.pitt.edu/~sussmanm/2070/lab_05/lab_05.html).  However, for $n=4$, the solver fails to converge (or at least has numerical issues).

---

The question again: What is a good choice of $f_i$ such that I can reconstruct $\vec{x}$ given $\vec{c}$?

Comment: It almost looks like you want a real-valued Fourier transform.  (Except for the permutation bit.)

Comment: What's the use of your <sup><sub> tags? On my computer, it has only the effect of making text so small that it's almost unreadable.

Comment: I don't understand if the constrains and the "simplifying" assumptions make this problem either trivial or impossible. Your attempt opens some weird questions about what you can/cannot do. Let me explain. Can the following: $f_j(x_i) = x_i \delta_{ij}$, where $\delta_{ij}$ is Kronecker's delta, be used? Is it compatible with your constraints? Your answer will answer my (unwritten) questions.

Comment: @PseudoRandom The functions $f_j$ are not themselves functions of the values they are given. So, a (bounded) delta function is acceptable, but useless.

Comment: @imallett: I don't think I get your point: isn't the index considered part of the input? The $f_j(x_i)$ I choosed use both $x_i$ and the indices. Kronecker's delta is strictly bounded (in fact, it is either 1 or 0, $\delta_{ij}=1 \iff i=j$, 0 otherwise) and when $i=j$, the output of $f_j$ is $x_i$, otherwise it's 0. For example, $f_1(x_1) = x_1$, but any other index $k \neq 1$ makes $f_1(x_k) =0$. With this trick, you get the numerical values directly in the vector $\vec{c}$. It's everything based on indices, that's why I don't know if it is acceptable.

Comment: @PseudoRandom the problem is that by making the functions $f_j$ depend on the inputs $x_i$ (by shifting the delta function to line up with $x_i$) is that this makes $f_j$ a function of its own arguments. What you're really suggesting is (borrowing ternary operator) $f_{j,x_i}(a):=(a==x_i)?1:0$. Note the subscript on $f$. This only works if I knew the $x_i$s beforehand (I don't).

Comment: @imallett: Then, how can you do $f_j(x_i) = x_i^j$ if $x$, $j$ and $i$ are unknown? Every function is a function of its own arguments, I don't get what you really want to say. The ternary operator cannot be used that way: the way you wrote it, the output is either 1 or 0 (a boolean value), which is not my case, and there is no arbitrary $a$ involved. The output of the function I proposed is either $x_i$ (with appropriate index $i$) or $0$. There is no hidden parameter. Check Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) if it's the first time you see $\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: @PseudoRandom: Ah, I think I was thinking of Dirac delta. Regardless, let's try this again: we can't define $f_j(x_i)=x_i\cdot\delta(i,j)$ because we don't have $i$. We actually have $f_j(a)=a\cdot\delta(???,j)$, since we have no idea what the $x_i$s are or what order we get them in. We could define some $f_j(a,i)$ and fix the problem, but unfortunately, $f_j$ must _only_ be a function of $a$ (which again is some $x_i$ of some unknown index $i$).

Comment: @imallett: Ok, we are coming closer. Now answer the question in my previous comment: how can you (like both the current answer and your example do) do $f_j(x_i) = x_i^j$ if the index $i$ is unknown? Answer: you can't, because you correctly assumed (like me) that the index is part of the input. Implicitly, we always have $f_j(a,i,j)$ ($j$ is not a problem, since we can pick it as we wish). But, for my answer to work, you do not actually need $i$. Permutations are irrelevant, thus you can re-label the indices (re-indexing $\vec{x}$) to get a permutation of $\vec{x}$ in $\vec{c}$.

Comment: Let me give an example. You receive $x_3$ first, but that $3$ is unknown. You re-label it $\tilde{x}_1$ and let the function do its work to get $c_1 = \tilde{x}_1 = x_3$. You then receive $x_1$, with $1$ unknown, re-label $\tilde{x}_2$ and let the function work to get $c_2 = \tilde{x}_2 = x_1$. And so on. If, by chance, the re-indexing was perfect ($\tilde{x}_i = x_i$ for every $i$), you get $\vec{c}=\vec{x}$. If not, $\vec{c}$ contains a (somewhat random) permutation of $\vec{x}$. But the numerical values are correct.

Comment: @PseudoRandom: $f_j(x_i)=x_i^j$ is fine because that function does not depend on $i$. The function $f_j(x_i)=x_i^i$ would _not_ be okay. Put another way, the index _of the function_ is part of the input. The index of the argument is not. Also, renumbering isn't feasible since then the function needs to implicitly keep track of how many times it has been called.

Comment: @imallett: Ok, I didn't know you couldn't keep track of how many times you call a function. But it doesn't matter, at this point, since my argument was essentially based on some type (albeit very weak) of index-knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of setting $f_i(x)=x^i$ actually works quite well:

Observation 1: The $n$ sums $$c_i=\sum_{j=1}^n f_i(x_j)$$ with $1\leq i\leq n$ can be used to express all the [elementary symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) $$e_k(\vec{x})=\sum_{\substack{A\subseteq \{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\} \\ |A|=k}}\prod_{x\in A}x$$ with $0\leq k\leq n$.

Observation 2: The polynomial $$P(X)=\prod_{i=1}^n (X-x_i)$$ can be expressed using these elementary symmetric polynomials as $$P(X)=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k e_k(\vec{x}) X^{n-k}$$

Observation 3: The roots of polynomial $P(X)$ are precisely the numbers $x_i$. Since it is a polynomial of single variable, its roots can be obtained either explicitly (for $n\leq 4$) or one can use any of the numeric algorithms quite easily (especially if all of them are distinct).

A few small examples of observation 1 look as follows (borrowing the notation used for $c_k$ and omitting the vector $\vec{x}$ in $e_k(\vec{x})$).
$$\begin{eqnarray}
e_1 & = & c_1 \\
e_2 & = & \frac{1}{2}\left(c_1^2-c_2\right)\\ 
e_3 & = & \frac{1}{6}\left(c_1^3-3c_1c_2+2c_3\right) \\
e_4 & = & \frac{1}{24}\left(c_1^4-6c_2c_1^2+3c_2^2+8c_3c_1-6c_4\right)\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

It might look surprising at the first glance, but the expressions on the right-hand side really do not depend on the number of variables.

Comment: +1 for teaching me about elementary SP (and for being only responder).¶  So the idea is to compute $\vec{c}(\vec{x})$ using $f_i(x_j):=x_j^i$, then convert to ESP with some simple function $\vec{e}:=\vec{g}(\vec{c}(\vec{x}))$.  Then we can calculate coefficients of $P(X):=\sum\cdots$.  Then, since $P(X)$ also is $\prod (X-x_i)$, the roots of $P(X)$ (found numerically) are exactly $\vec{x}$.  Right?  If so, I think this is just a permutation of what I already tried.  If it makes $P(X)$ better conditioned ($n\ge 4$), then it would be an acceptable partial solution.  Could you show that?